# Can't get value to be passed from input tag to database via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a webpage and have the total price displayed using javascript :

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price");
    price.value = getCodeValue() * twoWeekPrice();
}
```

which is then being used in the input tag:

```
<label>Total Price</label>
<input id="price" type="text" name="totalprice" value="">
```

Which is then being passed onto another page "insertbooking.php" where it is added to the database:

```
$getname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]);
$getnum = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST["telephonenum"]);
$getemail = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST["email"]);
$getcheckin = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST["checkin"]);
$getnumdays = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST["numdays"]);
$getprice = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST["totalprice"]);

$convertdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($getcheckin));

$insertquery = "INSERT INTO booking ( id, name, telephonenum, email, checkin, numdays, price) VALUES (NULL, '$getname', '$getnum', '$getemail', '$convertdate', '$getnumdays ', '$getprice)";
```

But I'm getting errors when I try to carry it out on the website any ideas?

Comment: Which errors you get?

Comment: What's the value of your input `price` ? Maybe not the format expected in database (`int` as `float` or other)

Comment: Do you actually call calculateTotal() somewhere?

Comment: The error is "Notice: Undefined variable: totalprice on line 16"

Comment: When I'm on the webpage calculateTotal() is displayed on the page its just whenever I go to submit it won't work. Its as if when I am on one page calculateTotal() inserts the total into the input tag but once it is trying to be accessed in $getprice I can't obtain the price.

Comment: price is a varchar

Comment: And what do you have on line 16? Please be as more detailed and specific as you can in order that we can help you. in this way that we have to ask you questions and move on step by step, you may not get a good answer

Comment: Please update your post, create a minimal version of your `html` & `<form>`, a minimal version of your `JavaScript` and also a minimal version of your `php` that we can actually track even without your assistance...